# Velocities of waves (such as visible light, and radio)

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light

The speed of light in a vacuum is a constant 299,792,458 m/s. In water, it is much slower. Does this happen to such waves as radio, or X-ray? (Would say, a 3 meter wavelength travel slower in air than in vacuum? And the same situation for an X-ray?)

Comment: You mean the refractive index? Yes, that can range from slightly less than one for x-rays (with absorption), one to approx. four for optical materials to much larger quantities for low frequency dielectric and ferromagnetic materials (although absorption will probably overwhelm the real part of the refractive index for those materials, again). Finally, meta-materials can now tune the refractive index for microwaves over a wide range. I also think you got a very good question there: What's the material with the highest refractive index that can still carry a whole wavelength at some frequency?

Comment: Related question on EE.SE: [Why does the speed of the Electromagnetic wave in the material depend on the frequency of the wave where as they are constant in vacuum (freespace)?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/)

Comment: "A terahertz metamaterial with unnaturally high refractive index", Muhan Choi et al, Nature 470, 369–373 (17 February 2011) reports a meta-material with a refractive index of 38.6 in the terahertz range. I think that's quite impressive.

Comment: Also fun: a plasma can have an index of refraction below one. Light won't actually move faster than $c$, but the wavelength of a given frequency will be longer than in a vacuum. The effect increases as frequency goes down.